# Get the name of the physically (on front of pc) logged in user, reliably!

Tags: session, kdm

`w`, `who`, `id` and `whoami` are excluded, because they only give information about users using a tty. Is there a way to extract the name reliably from KDM?

Comment: You write "the logged in user" as if Unix were a single-user system. Are you assuming there is only one display, and no remote access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those command do not track users that don't use a TTY.

The magic command is `loginctl` (systemd).

Answer (score 4):

What about the commands `users` and `last`.

#### users

```
   users - print the user names of users currently logged in to the current host
```

Makes use of the `/var/run/utmp` and `/var/log/wtmp` files.

#### last

```
   last, lastb - show listing of last logged in users
```

Makes use of the `/var/log/wtmp` log file. Shows historically the last time a user logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the auth-log for getting this information.

Example for CentOS5: `aureport -l` another possibility is using the `last` command.